# Dynamically modify output alert content on submit form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I currently have a page that contains a form and a hidden validation div thats being used for alert:

```
<body>
   <form id="1">
       <input id="2">
       <button id="submitButton" type="button">Submit</button>
   </form>


   <div id="alert">
       <span>Input is empty!</span>
   </div>

</body>
```

On page load, the alert div is hidden with CSS:

```
#alert{
    display: none;
}
```

There is a JS validation file that is being used to check if input  is empty on submit. This JS file cannot be changed.

If the input tag is empty when click submit button, the JS will perform a simple jQuery `show()` function so the div will be visible to the user:

```
if(isEmptyField){
  $('#alert').show();
}
```

Now, I cannot modify the "Input is empty!" string that exist in the span tag, however, I want to change the alert message to "Empty input!".

How do I create a jQuery event to achieve this? So when I click the Submit button, I will see "Empty input!" instead of "Input is empty!"?

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the original JS file, simply change the line to this:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
    if (isEmptyField) {
        $('#alert span').text("Empty input!").show();
    }
});
```

Otherwise, you can change the span's text when the document loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#alert span').text("Empty input!");
});
```

Comment: Would this work? There is already a JS file does this. Would this override the current one?

Comment: @JasonZ if you can edit the original js file, then replace it with this. Make sure the "isEmptyField" variable is still valid. otherwise use the second example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the submit form

example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzf3v6ch/)

jQuery;

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if ( $( "input" ).val() == "" ) {
    $( "span" ).text( "Input is empty!" ).show();
    return false;
  }

  $( "span" ).text( "Thanks" ).show().fadeOut( 2000 );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Markup

```
<body>
   <form id="1">
       <input id="2">
       <button id="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
   <div id="alert">
       <span></span>
   </div>
</body>
```

you dont need `#alert` css anymore